# Tomcat 7.0.53 SSL connection not connecting

Tags: tomcat, ssl

I am trying to use tomcat with SSL by using the following `server.xml` file

```
<!--Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
     This connector uses the BIO implementation that requires the JSSE
     style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
     OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
     documentation -->
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
       SSLCertificateFile="/home/Desktop/keys/cert.pem"
       SSLCertificateKeyFile="/home/Desktop/keys/key.pem"
       SSLPassword="pass"
       />
```

and I keep getting the error in my chrome console that `GET http://localhost:8443/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`. According to the tomcat log, there seems to be no errors with starting the server

```
Sep 18, 2014 11:45:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.30 using APR version 1.3.9.
Sep 18, 2014 11:45:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
Sep 18, 2014 11:45:59 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013)
Sep 18, 2014 11:45:59 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Sep 18, 2014 11:45:59 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8443"]
Sep 18, 2014 11:45:59 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Sep 18, 2014 11:45:59 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 518 ms
Sep 18, 2014 11:45:59 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 18, 2014 11:45:59 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.53
Sep 18, 2014 11:45:59 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/webapps/websocket.war
Sep 18, 2014 11:45:59 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/webapps/docs
Sep 18, 2014 11:45:59 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/webapps/examples
Sep 18, 2014 11:46:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/webapps/ROOT
Sep 18, 2014 11:46:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/webapps/host-manager
Sep 18, 2014 11:46:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/webapps/manager
Sep 18, 2014 11:46:00 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Sep 18, 2014 11:46:00 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8443"]
Sep 18, 2014 11:46:00 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Sep 18, 2014 11:46:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1097 ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right before I pressed post question I found out the answer, I was entering the address as `localhost:8443` when it needed to be `https://localhost:8443/`